# Python Divmod help for a mathematical exercise for beginner

Tags: python, numbers, int, division, divmod

So basically all I am trying to do is take the third and forth digits from a set of numbers:

```
# Number Set
num_set = (28,54,79,37,2,9,0)
```

and divide them both(79 and 37), This is the code I have written:

```
# Division of third and fourth digits
# Seperating the digits
div_num = ((num_set[2,3]))
print("we are going to divide", div_num)
ans = (divmod(div_num))
print("the answer for 79 divide by 37 is", ans)
```

which gives me the error

> "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to replace this line of code

```
ans = (divmod(div_num))
```

with:

```
ans = divmod(num_set[2], num_set[3])
```

You don't need `div_num` so remove all its references.

---

**Why do you get your error?**

`num_set[2,3]` is same as `num_set[(2,3)]`. You are trying to index a tuple by a tuple when it should be by integers or slices.

---

**Code**:

```
ans = divmod(num_set[2], num_set[3])
print("the answer for 79 divide by 37 is", ans)
```

Comment: Thanks @Austin, The code does work, but I do need to display which numbers I am dividing, thus the reason for using `div_num` so how would I go about doing that ?

Comment: Hello, you can use `print("we are going to divide", num_set[2], num_set[3])`. Please don't forget to accept the helpful answer by pressing tick on the left of answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use word `set` as it is a type in python

With f-strings

```py
num_list = [28, 54, 79, 37, 2, 9, 0]

n, p = num_list[2:4]
print(f"we are going to divide {n} by {p}")
q, r = divmod(n, p)
print(f"the answer for {n} divide by {p} \
is {q} and a remainder of {r}")
```

edit:
`[2:4]` is a slice of 4-2=2 elements.

When a function returns more than one items, you can assign them to variables.

f-strings (strings prefixed with `f`) will replace variables in between braces with their values.